# Resize texture in code

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I need to change texture size from for example 800x600 to 80x60. I have two ideas of how to do that, but i have problems with both approaches.
1) changre render target then draw and save resized. the problem is blinking screen while this method is working.

```
public static Texture2D Resize(Texture2D image, Rectangle source)
        {
            var graphics = image.GraphicsDevice;

            var ret = new RenderTarget2D(graphics, source.Width, source.Height);
            var sb = new SpriteBatch(graphics);

            graphics.SetRenderTarget(ret); // draw to image
            graphics.Clear(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

            sb.Begin();
            sb.Draw(image, source, Color.White);
            sb.End();

            graphics.SetRenderTarget(null); // set back to main window

            return (Texture2D)ret;
        }
```

2) use Texture.SaveAsPng(); this aproach is extremly stupid but it works

```
public static Texture2D Resize(Texture2D banner,Rectangle rectangle)
        {

                using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (var IsolatedStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("banner.te2", FileMode.Create, file))
                    {
                        IsolatedStream.Position = 0;
                        banner.SaveAsPng(IsolatedStream, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
                        IsolatedStream.Close();
                    }
                }

                if (IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().FileExists("banner.te2"))
                {
                    using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        var IsolatedStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("banner.te2", FileMode.Open, file);
                        IsolatedStream.Position = 0;
                        banner = Texture2D.FromStream(Consts.GraphicsDevice, IsolatedStream);
                        IsolatedStream.Close();
                    }
                }
                return banner;

        }
```

I'm looking for a clean fast solution, any suggestions? Resizing in `Draw()` method is not solution for me.

Comment: Oh great. It's that horridly wrong copy-pasted resizing code from XNA 3.1 being passed around. It was bad then, and doesn't even work in XNA 4.

Comment: Do you mean resize or crop?

Comment: Resize, i need to do icon from full texture.

Comment: Your `RenderTarget2D` method appears to be doing a crop.

Comment: Actually not, `sb.Draw(image, source, Color.White);` second parameter is rectangle, if there were `Vector2` it would be crop.

Comment: Ah of course! Got confused because the variable's name is "source" (probably should be "destination", as per `Draw` itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the render target, by default, will clear the render target that you set. (In this case, `null` specifies the backbuffer as the render target - it gets cleared too).

You can change this by setting `RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents` on the appropriate backbuffer. To do this, you need to respond to the `PreparingDeviceSettings` event at startup and set `GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.RenderTargetUsage`.

If you are on any platform other than Windows (so, on Windows Phone or Xbox 360), then this is ***not*** recommended because it's very, very slow - which is why it is not the default.

Rather than changing modes, you should simply do all your render target operations at the *start* of your frame, before you draw your scene to the backbuffer. In your `Update` method is acceptable.

Note that "`return (Texture2D)ret`" doesn't turn your render target into a regular `Texture2D`. It's still a `RenderTarget2D` object and you must respond correctly to `IsContentLost` (or redraw it every frame, or copy it into a `Texture2D` with `GetData` and `SetData`).

---

**A better solution than all of this**, however, is probably to simply copy the original `Texture2D` into another `Texture2D` using `GetData` and `SetData` (performing whatever transform you want to apply on the CPU - if it is a simple crop operation, then this will be very fast).

Comment: Target platform is windows phone, so am i right i have only one good solution of this problem by using `SetData` and writing my own resize algorithm of the texture?

Comment: No no - you can still do it on the GPU if you like. You should just be sure to do one of those three things I mentioned (refresh the render target each frame, refresh it on content lost, or copy it back to the CPU).